# runtime error when using sklearn in python3.2 (works fine in python 2.7) - how to fix it?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I am trying to learn sklearn and I encounter the below error when I run `import sklearn` . However, when I run the exact same code using python 2.7, I do not encounter any errors.

```
    import sklearn
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from .base import clone
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy import sparse
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 124, in <module>
    pkgload(verbose=SCIPY_IMPORT_VERBOSE,postpone=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/numpy/_import_tools.py", line 177, in __call__
    for package_name in self._get_sorted_names():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/numpy/_import_tools.py", line 114, in _get_sorted_names
    for name in depend_dict.keys():
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

I did some googl'ing and followed the instructions from the following link and ran `sudo pip3 install git+https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn.git`. The installation went fine, however, I continue to get the error.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/449326/installation-error-in-sklearn-for-python3

How does one go about fixing this issue. (other than working with Python2.7)

Comment: can you update to python 3.4?

Comment: I did not downvote, I am just asking you but it does not matter I see there is an issue with 3.4 also.

Comment: ok then, whoever downvoted is crazy. would you happen to have any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: what do you get if you `import numpy numpy.__version__` from a python3 shell

Comment: well the issue is not numpy then, why can't you upgrade to python 3.4?installing from git as you have will work with python 3.4, you will need scipy also

Comment: I thought you mentioned the same issue with 3.4 also.

Comment: using pip is an issue with 3.4, installing as per the link will work.Unless you are unable to for some specific reason I would upgrade to python 3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug that's that will be fixed in the next NumPy (v 1.9.0) release:

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/5025c40965fa5fb2b591f07c152b966dc7b730f0

There is already a patch available on github, but it hasn't been bundled into a patch release yet. Your options:

1. Wait for the 1.9.0 release to fix for Python 3, and use Python 2 in the meantime.
2. Simply apply the same changes to the two lines in the link I provided to your current version of Numpy
3. Install Numpy 1.9.0 beta.

Comment: which version(s) of numpy have the bug?

Comment: I'm not sure. All I know is they just became aware of it.

Comment: where do I apply the changes?

Comment: It's right in the stack trace: `/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/numpy/_import_tools.py`

Comment: so this is specific to python < 3.4?

Comment: Yes - since in Python3k, `keys()` returns an iterator instead of a list.

Comment: so upgrading to python 3.4 will fix the issue?

Comment: @Padraic I'm not under that impression. Can you link me to what change in 3.4 changed this behaviour?

Comment: ok, for whatever it is worth, I downgraded to numpy 1.6.1 and matplotlib 1.3.1 and I am not getting the runtime error.I will have to run some examples to find out if I run into any problems. and since several kind folks have downvoted my q?, I cannot upvote anyone's response.

Comment: That is why I asked, I think the issue is with numpy > 1.8.1 so in this particular instance upgrading to python 3.4 and using the git install method will work. There must be a bug in python 3.2 that is causing the OP's issue as I have no issue using 1.8.1 and installing as per the link.

Comment: I see. I almost 100% certain this issue won't be fixed in Python 3.4 The bug is happening because the `keys()` function is not returning a copy of the keys as it would in Python 2. In Python 3 it's returning an iterator to the original list, and you aren't allowed to modify the original list you are looping over inside of said loop.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I appreciate your suggestion. I am such a newbie that I'd prefer to not take the risk of encountering any potential bugs with 3.4. Perhaps as I learn and get more comfy with it, I will upgrade

Comment: @MartinKonecny, I understand the error but I think there is also some bug related to using  python 3.2.

Comment: @user3766123, python 3.4 includes bug fixes and improvements, I would not worry about using new stable python releases.

Comment: I just tried an example with `sklearn` and I get the following error (in both 2.7.3 and 3.2.3) but when I run the same code on IPython (which I understand is using 2.7), I don't get the error. How does that happen?:`python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Feb 27 2014, 20:00:17) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sklearn import decomposition
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name decomposition`. this won't go away with 3.4, will it?

Comment: may I say yes:-(. I deleted that and I get another error `from sklearn import decomposition
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/decomposition/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .nmf import NMF, ProjectedGradientNMF
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/decomposition/nmf.py", line 21, in <module>`

Comment: `from ..utils import atleast2d_or_csr, check_random_state, check_arrays
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
  File "numpy.pxd", line 155, in init sklearn.utils.murmurhash (sklearn/utils/murmurhash.c:5029)
ValueError: numpy.dtype has the wrong size, try recompiling` what do I need to recompile?